# How to change from for to foreach

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, ldap

I am trying to format two sets of results to appear in similar tables.  One is a MySQL query and one is an ldap query.  The only problem is with one the results are displayed with a foreach loop, the other is counting through the results, and I'm not sure how to make one work with the other.

```
/* This is the MySQL query.  I am pulling the info and creating 
 * a table with the results.  The #$header array is the columns
 * of the table.  Then foreach result, I put the $results of my
 * query in the same order as my columns. */

$results = db_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `".$searchParams."`='".$input."'");

$header = array(
  t('First Name'),
  t('Last Name'),
  t('Passport Number'),
  t('VISA Type'),
  t('Step in Process')
  );
  $rows = array();
 foreach($results as $result){
     $rows[] = array(
         $result-> first_name,
         $result -> last_name,
         $result -> gwf,
         $result -> visa_type,
         $result -> current_stage,
         );
 }

 return theme('table', array('header'=>$header,'rows'=>$rows));


/*Here is how I'm currently displaying my ldap_search() results*/
$ds=ldap_connect("ldap-server");  
if ($ds) { 
$r=ldap_bind($ds);     
    $sr=ldap_search($ds, "DC=,DC=co,DC=uk", $search);  
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr)
       for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
            echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
            echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
            echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
}
```

How can I change the ldap results so that I can use the same foreach to create the table I am creating with my mysql results?  I'm sorry if this is very simple, I'm still trying to wrap my head around loops, counting, and things like that.

Comment: Where is `$info` coming from?

Comment: Added the entire php query, showing $info

Comment: You can do it all within the `foreach`, just add an index, e.g. `foreach($results as $index => $result)`

Answer (score 1):

there is a slight trick but essentially you can do the same with foreach. change this line:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
```

to this:

```
foreach ($info as $i => $val) {
    if($i == "count")
    continue;
    echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
    echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
    echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
}
```

continue line is for `$info["count"]`, that is not a row and you need to ignore that while looping.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't understand what you are ssaying about the continue line.  where do I set the order that the fields are printed in the row of the table I am creating? (the $rows array) Does that just come after continue?

Comment: yes, edited my answer to include full foreach block.

Answer (score 1):

To add to my comment :

> You can do it all within the `foreach`, just add an index, e.g. `foreach($results as $index => $result)`

For example

```
foreach($results as $index => $result) {
  if (isset($info[$index])) {
    // use both $result and $info 
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `$results` have to do with `$info` they are two different arrays coming from two different sources. What makes you think the keys and the number of keys would match?

Comment: @Pitchinnate The result of the query will be a Drupal `DatabaseStatementInterface` which implements `Iterator` - meaning it will be numerically indexed in the `foreach`. The `for` loop starts at `0` and with the `isset()` you will always know it exists.

Comment: What happens if there are 10 results from they mysql query and 100 results from the LDAP search. You would only display 10 of the 100 results from LDAP search.

Comment: $results and $info have nothing to do with each other...I'm sorry, I thought I explained it in my question. I'm still new to this. My question isnt about the two queries at all, they arent even from the same web site. My question is about formatting the results on my first site, I am using mysql to do a search and then displaying the results in a table.  In my second site, I am using ldap to search, but want to format the results in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Not a hundred percent sure I understand what you are looking for but I believe this is it:

```
$header = array(
  t('DN'),
  t('CN'),
  t('Email'),
);

foreach ($info as $i => $val) {
    //this causes the $info['count'] row to be ignored
    if($i == "count")
    continue;

    $rows[] = array(
        $val["dn"],
        $val["cn"][0],
        $val["mail"][0]
    );
}
```